# Unable to run Google Cloud Vision on Firebase Emulator

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-tools, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to test Google Cloud Vision(GCV) on Firebase Emulator using Cloud Functions where the GCV will detect labels and update corresponding Firestore documents.

I'm coming across 2 problems:

1. GCV won't accept requests from `demo-project`. 7_PERMISSION DENIED error which basically means that `demo-project` isn't allowed to make requests to it. I then changed the projectId locally to what it is on GCP. Now requests are accepted.
2. Once I change to GCP projectId, GVC looks for images in my live GCP buckets and doesn't find the images since they are on the storage emulator.

How does one test GCV either locally through emulator or at least without it being a live production environment? Please point me in the right direction.